# SalesForce access key token generation in SSIS

Tags: ssis, salesforce

I am trying to pull SalesForce data into Sql server using MSBI ETL tools. I'm using script task for authenticating the SalesForce Access token. But the access token expires every 12 hrs and I've to manually generate a new access token and update into ETL before executing package. 
Is there any possibilities for a permanent access token key or any any way to generate access token key using refresh token key. Please help me on this issues.